# Decision trees: information gain - bias against attributes - how and why is it say so?

Tags: decision-tree

I am confused to get the context on biases in the following line (marked in bold):

Information gain ratio **biases the decision tree against considering attributes with a large number of distinct values** which might lead to overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean Information gain, as information gain is bias towards variables with large distinct values and information gain ratio is tries to solve this by taking into account the number of branches that would result before making the split, It corrects information gain by taking the intrinsic information of a split into account.

**Answer for why information gain is biased towards variables with large distinct values**

*Please note that information gain (IG) is biased toward variables with large number of distinct values not variables that have observations with large values. Before describing the reason of this condition, lets review the definition of IG.*

*Information gain is the amount of information that's gained by knowing the value of the attribute, which is the entropy of the distribution before the split minus the entropy of the distribution after it. The largest information gain is equivalent to the smallest entropy.*

*In other words, a variable with the highest number of distinct values probability can divide data to smaller chunks. Also, we know that lower number of observations in each chunk reduces probability of variation occurrence.*

*Using ID variable in splitting data is a common example for this issue. Since each individual sample has their own distinct value, selecting ID features leads to many clusters with one sample and entropy of zero. Therefore, a decision tree that works with IG, selects the ID as the first separator attribute. Indeed, entropy will approach to zero by selecting the ID feature. However, we are not interested to such a feature. We are more interested to features that highly explain the variation of dependent variable.*

Please refer to this [discussion](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-disadvantage-of-using-Information-Gain-for-feature-selection) where this point was initially written.